# How do I get rid of youtube-dl?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, youtube, youtube-dl

It looks like youtube-dl is permanently stuck on my system. Months back I installed it (I don't know how). But now I'm desperately trying to uninstall it. All the uninstall commands say that it's not installed, yet I'm using it in the terminal and that means it's installed.

I installed it as snap. I can see many youtube-dl leftover files in snap folders. Is there a way to clear them all?

Comment: How you remove something depends upon how you installed it. Use the `whereis` command to determine where the application is installed -- that's a clue to how it was installed.

Comment: Is it installed as Flatpak? Also, what is the output of `which youtube-dl`?

Comment: youtube-dl: /home/user/.local/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: I think I might have installed it as a snap, but I uninstalled it using sudo snap remove youtube-dl but it's still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have installed it manually. Then the package system does not know about it. So in that case delete the executable manually to remove it again. It likely will be in `/usr/local/bin`, but you can make sure with the `which` command.

Comment: I deleted it manually like you said and it worked.

Comment: I installed it as snap. I can see many youtube-dl leftover files in snap folders. Any way to clear them all?

Comment: You gave output of 'snap remove' that indicates the snap is not installed. You can delete anything you see under your home folder (this is never autodeleted) and remains in the snap system will automatically be cleared after thirty days.